# not able to create workspace as its telling i am not sudo user

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i am trying to create workspace through sudo apt-get----------- it is telling the user is not a sudo user so what should i do now and how to create the workspace now

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48036/not-able-to-create-workspace-as-its-telling-i-am-not-sudo-user/) by [Udhaysimha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3570/udhaysimha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-11**:
Please be more specific. For instance, provide the exact steps you did when getting the error message. Please read http://ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you trying to do? You don't need to use apt-get to create a workspace. Are you sure you did all the tutorials here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

To use apt-get to install packages, you have to have sudo-rights, so you will have to ask your admin to install packages... However, to create a ROS workspace, you don't need it anyway...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1